# PhoneGap RevMob plugin ads not loading

Tags: cordova, revmob

I can't seem to get the PhoneGap RevMob plugin to work on iOS.  I followed the installation instructions on the Github page, but no ads are displayed on my app.  My index.html code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function onDeviceReady() {
            RevMob.initWithAppId("APP-ID");
        }

    function onBodyLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="onBodyLoad()">
</body>
```

It also appears that the revmob.js file is not loaded in my app.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

PS: I am using Phonegap 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used cli to add the plugin? (cordova plugin add) If not, add the revmob.js manually.

In order for ads to show up, you must call them, for instance RevMob.showFullscreen(successCallback, errorCallback);